# How to integrate OpenLDAP to Keycloak correctly?

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, openldap

Installed OpenLDAP by helm

```
helm install openldap stable/openldap
```

Check data in the initialized server

```
kubectl port-forward $OPENLDAP_POD_NAME 3890:389
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://localhost:3890 -b dc=example,dc=org -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" -w $LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example.org
dn: dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example

# admin, example.org
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword:: [HIDDEN]

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntries: 2
```

Install keycloak

```
helm install keycloak codecentric/keycloak
kubectl port-forward $KEYCLOAK_POD_NAME 8080
```

Bind it to Keycloak in the `User Federation` -> `Add user storage provider` -> `ldap` as below.

[image]

Why can't connect to ldap server? I login to the ldap pod to see the log but didn't find where is it.

Comment: Add output from `kubectl get all`. If special namespace used add `-n {namespace}` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Connection URL" should most probably be `ldap://openldap.default:389` (and if `openldap` was deployed in a different namespace, replace `default` with that).